# Check if any children exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

Considering these two tables:

> Position(positionid, positiontext, reportstopositionid)
>
> User(userid, positionid)

How can I check if a user has any subordinates in one query?
Is it even possible?

A subordinate:
user (a) with positionid has at least one or more subordinates if there exists any users (b) with the positionid of user (a) as reportstopositionid to users (b) corresponding positionid

Comment: What is a subordinate? Do all users in a position report to all user in the super-ordinate position?

Comment: Do you only want to check if a user has subordinates?, not the list of all subordinates?

Comment: @SWeko: user (a) with positionid has at least one or more subordinates if there exists any users (b) with the positionid of user (a) as reportstopositionid to users (b) corresponding positionid

Comment: @Lamak: That's not so important. Need to find a way to query for subordinates.

Answer (score 2):

This will return users who have subordinates:

```
SELECT *
FROM   User u
WHERE  EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM   Position p
           WHERE  p.reportstopositionid = u.positionid
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this one?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    user a
        INNER JOIN position b
            ON a.userID = b.reportstopositionID
```

the records returned by this query are those which has matching IDs `userid` on `position` table at column `reportstopositionID`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this with a `where` clause:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.positionId in (select reportstopositionid from position p)
```

This gets the list of users who match, without duplicates.

Comment: userid does not correspond to positionid

Comment: @sjallamander . . . It always helps to clarify the relationship in the question.